# How to switch between multiple .xcassets files

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcasset, uiimageasset

We have 3 targets for 3 different apps offering similar sets of features but different UI.
all these 3 targets are having different .xcassets files. But now as per Apple 4.3 guideline, they are asking us to create one container and handle different UI from the same container.

Now as we already have different image assets files for different targets, how can I programmatically switch between different .xcassets files.

Comment: Why not put them all into one `.xcassets` file and set the device usage of each asset?

Comment: At the moment I have different images with same name in every xcassets file. Any way I don't want to handle multiple conditions while assigning every image, rather I would prefer to load specific xcasset file on load.

Comment: you can directly access the images from `.xcassets`, you just have to check for target you are using.

Comment: @PrafulKadam yeah, even I am also using a similar way to access images from `xcassets`

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple `xcassets` for multiple targets, let's say you have A, B, C target and have three different `xcassets` for each target, you can solve this issue with two ways:

1. Add images with the same name for different targets and access the images directly. Xcode will run time access specific `xcassets` images.
2. Add checks for different targets at the time of accessing images

Coding Example:

```
if target == "A" {
   let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "firstImage"))
}
if target == "B" {
  let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "secondImage"))
}
if target == "C" {
  let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "thirdImage"))
}
```

Comment: I have different images with same image name like 'firstImage' in all xcassets.

Comment: @PrafulKadam Then you will have to add a check for targets.

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger can u tell how to access target in view controllers i.e can u tell main declaration of target variable which u r using in above example?

Comment: @jayantrawat You can use the user-defined section under the project's build setting to add target based variables to distinguish between targets.

Comment: Use the following link to understand how to add a user-defined setting: https://www.thetopsites.net/article/52433707.shtml

Answer (score 0):

First I have created multiple image version is same xcasset file and then
I created an extension for UIImage and wrote convenience initializer where I check the current target and assign image name accordingly

```
extension UIImage {

convenience init?(editableNamed: String) {
    let newName = appDel.target != "target1" ? editableNamed : "\(editableNamed)_target1"
    if (UIImage(named: newName) != nil) {
        self.init(named: newName)
    }
    else {
        self.init(named: editableNamed)
    }
}
```

So whenever I assign image like

```
cell.imgCheck.image = UIImage(editableNamed: "iconCheck")
```

It checks the current target and then assigns appropriate image from xcasset file.